CSV with Coordinates in QGIS
I want to upload a CSV in QGIS (add layer "Data source manager", "delimiter text"). Every time when I'm uploading the file it won't show me as a point layer.
What am I doing wrong?



Are your coordinates for sure in DMS format (degrees minutes seconds)?

Perhaps you could share the first few lines of data so others can better help you. it might also be that the file is loading correctly but not plotting where you are looking- you can check this by right-clicking its entry in the table of contents and selecting "Zoom to Layer(s)"

Eventually your coordinates are actually in EPSG:4326, not 4979? Eventually your decimalseparator is comma? We can only wild guess with the provided information...

Don't tick the "GMS-Koordinaten" box. Your Latitude/Longitude fields are double precision so almost certainly in decimal degrees, not Degree/Minute/Second (GMS in German?).
Also you should use EPSG:4326 for WGS 84. Not sure what 4979 is, some 3D coordinate system?

epsg:4979 is WGS 84 Geographic 3D lat/long + height (https://epsg.org/crs_4979/WGS-84.html)

So they are interchangeable in QGIS?
